# An easy rebus - don't call n999

Tags: rebus

**n999**

> What is this a rebus for?

Hint:

> The answer can be found underground

Comment: does this have anything to do with your rep points at the time you posted the question?

Comment: It might @Marius - that's how I came up with it, but it doesn't actually matter what my rep is

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it:

> Mines

As in:

> n-nines
>
> nnines
>
> mines
>
>  They're underground

Comment: Absolutely correct, well done

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Hades

Logic:

> n could be 'not' as 'upside-down', and 999 upside-down is 666, which is the Devil's name, and he lives in the underworld, i.e. Hades.

Comment: Nice idea, but i'm afraid my idea was a lot simpler than that - I didn't even know 666 is the devil's name!